# Functions and Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting programming, I have this issue and I can't finish it. where to use `startsWith` inside the function?

```js
function werewolfCheck(name) {
  if (name === str.startsWith('were')) {
    return 'It is a werewolf';
  } else {
    return 'Just a regular person';
  }
}

var werewolfCheck = name.str.startsWith('were');
werewolfCheck('werebrian');
```

Comment: [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is a method of strings.  The `str.` before that is just to tell you to call it on a string.  `name.startsWith('were')` returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Task Instructions


Implement a function named werewolfCheck that receives an argument name, which is a string and checks if it begins with "were".

If the provided name begins with were the function should return a string "it is a werewolf", otherwise it should return a string "just a regular person".Important: You must use the keyword return to return the value from the function. Tests can only check the output value that your function returns. Any console.log output will be ignored.:

Comment: my code: function werewolfCheck (name) {
  if ( name === str.startsWith("were")){   
    return "it is a werewolf";
 } else {
   return "just a regular person";
 }
}

var werewolfCheck =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in the function `str` doesn't exist so you just need to check to see if `name` (the argument you passed in) starts with 'were'.
2. `var werewolfCheck...` does nothing useful so you can remove it.
3. The return from the function is a string so you need some way to display that string. I've logged it to the console in this example.

```js
function werewolfCheck(name) {
  if (name.startsWith('were')) {
    return 'It is a werewolf';
  } else {
    return 'Just a regular person';
  }
}

console.log(werewolfCheck('werebrian'));
console.log(werewolfCheck('Billy Joel'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function werewolfCheck(name){
    if(name.startsWith("were"))
      return "It is werewolf";
    return "Just a regular person";
  }

  werewolfCheck("werebrain");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ternary](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/) operator and [ES6 arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function as cleaner and more readable solution

```
const werewolfCheck = (name) => {
return name.startsWith('were') ? 'It is a werewolf' :'Just a regular person';
}

console.log(werewolfCheck('werebrian'));
console.log(werewolfCheck('Billy Joel'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function werewolfCheck (name) {
  if (name.slice(0,4) === "were"){
    return "it is a werewolf"
  } else {
    return "just a regular person"
  }
};
console.log(werewolfCheck("werebrian"))
```